# How to render enum values from dataclass on xhtml jsf page

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

i have an enum in my data-class as follows

public enum ProcStat 
    {

```
    NOT_READY               ((byte)-1, "Not Ready For Processing"),
    READY_FOR_PROCESSING    ((byte)0,  "Ready For Processing"),
    BEING_PROCESSED         ((byte)1,  "Being Processed"),
    PROCESSED_SUCCESSFULLY  ((byte)2,  "Processed Successfully"),
    MSG_SUPPRESSED          ((byte)98, "Msg suppressed before processing"),
    PROCESSED_ERROR         ((byte)99, "Processed With Error");

    private final Byte statByte; 
    private final String  statusDesc;
    ProcStat(Byte statByte, String statusDesc)
    {
        this.statByte = statByte;
        this.statusDesc = statusDesc;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return statusDesc;
    }
    protected static ProcStat getProcStat(Byte procStat)
    {
        if (READY_FOR_PROCESSING.statByte.equals(procStat))             
        {
            return READY_FOR_PROCESSING;
        }           
        else if (BEING_PROCESSED.statByte.equals(procStat))             
        {
            return BEING_PROCESSED;
        }
        else if (PROCESSED_SUCCESSFULLY.statByte.equals(procStat))
        {   
            return PROCESSED_SUCCESSFULLY;
        }
        else if (MSG_SUPPRESSED.statByte.equals(procStat))
        {   
            return MSG_SUPPRESSED;
        }           
        else if (PROCESSED_ERROR.statByte.equals(procStat))
        {
            return PROCESSED_ERROR;                 
        }
        else
        {
            return NOT_READY;
        }
    }
    public Byte getStatByte()
    {
        return this.statByte;
    }
};
```

The Proc_Stat refers to a Number field in a DataBase table and i need to show a column on the page where it shows the corresponding String of the numeric proc_stat for each row.
This is how i render any other field of the same data-class on the xhtml page:

id="dataTable" name="dataTable" var="data"

How do i give output value for enum type?
do i give like this  :    value="#{data.procstat.toString()}"  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create method in one of your managed bean that does the same as `getProcStat` method. Something like:

```
public String getProcStat(Byte byte) {
    return ProcState.getProcState(byte).toString();
}
```

In xhtml:

```
value="#{yourBean.getProcState(data)}"
```

Comment: i am already passing a list containing objects of my data class having all the instances including the enum value back from the DAO layer. All i need is a way to capture that field for each object on the xhtml page.  if i give it as you have suggested 
value="#{yourBean.getProcState(data)}"
that would mean making another call to the backing bean.